# Uncaught TypeError: ref.putString is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var ref = storageRef.child('nothing.txt');
ref.putString('nothing');
```

This is my code. put() function works without any problem but putString() gives an error on the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ref.putString is not a function
```

Comment: I think `putString()` was added in a more recent version (3.3 or 3.4 iirc). What version do you use?

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen Oh. It was 3.2. That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity: `putString()` was implemented in 3.3.0 as per the [changelog](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.3.0).