# Firebase Error -> storageRef.putString() is not a function. Trying to upload an image from a post to firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to take a post that contains an image and upload it to firebase storage.  Originally I had an error saying storage was not a function, but have change it to a new const as storageRef.

Now I am getting an error that .putString() isn't a function.  I am passing in an image from my state variable and "data_url" as the 2nd arg.  Why am I getting this error and is there anything else that seems to be off with my code?

Firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage, ref } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: '',
    appId: '',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage();
```

File where Error is happening:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { db, storage } from '../firebase';
import { collection, serverTimestamp, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { ref } from 'firebase/storage';

function InputBox() {
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const [imageToPost, setImageToPost] = useState(null);

    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const filePickerRef = useRef(null);

    const sendPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!inputRef.current.value) return;

        try {
            const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
                message: inputRef.current.value,
                name: session.user.name,
                email: session.user.email,
                image: session.user.email,
                timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            }).then((doc) => {
                if (imageToPost) {
                    const storageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${doc.id}`);
                    const uploadTask = storageRef.putString(imageToPost, 'data_url');
                    removeImage();

                    uploadTask.on(
                        'state_change',
                        null,
                        (error) => console.error(error),
                        () => {
                            // When upload completes
                            storageRef
                                .ref(`posts`)
                                .child(doc.id)
                                .getDownloadURL()
                                .then((url) => {
                                    docRef.addDoc(
                                        Collection(db, 'posts')
                                            .doc(doc.id)
                                            .set(
                                                {
                                                    postImage: url,
                                                },
                                                { merge: true }
                                            )
                                    );
                                });
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
            console.log(docRef.id);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR ADDING DOC:', e);
        }
```

Thanks in advance, Firebase is updating all the time and I still find this somewhat confusing.

Comment: Can you check your firebase/storage version if it has `.putString`. it's added in 3.3.0 as per https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.3.0

Comment: @MarcSimon well I'm using the latest update of Firebase, but when reading the docs on firebase it seems that .putString() is still a method.

Comment: what version of Firebase Storage do you use?Have a look at this stackoverfloe [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297721/upload-to-firebase-error-storage-ref-is-not-a-function) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874604/uncaught-typeerror-ref-putstring-is-not-a-function)